# String args discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making an rpg game with discord.py, and I've run into an issue. I'm looking to make a command where you can hunt for an input animal in an input biome, but I don't know how to make it so they can just select the name of the animal or biome instead of having to type it all in. Is it similar to how you do it with bool arguments, or is it completely different? here is my best guess at what the code could be for what I'm trying to do

```
locations=['woods','caves']
weapons=['sword','axe']
creatures=['fox','wolf']
@slash.slash(description='an rpg command to hunt creatures')
async def hunt(ctx,weapon:weapons,creature:creatures,location:locations):
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author} chose to hunt a {creature} with a {weapon} in {location}')
```

here is an example of what I mean from the dank memer bot
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/892410036565970967/964529376261705728/IMG_0252.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
@slash.slash(description='an rpg command to hunt creatures')
async def hunt(ctx, weapon: str = commands.Param(choices=['sword', 'axe']),creature: str = commands.Param(choices=['fox', 'wolf'],location: str = commands.Param(choices=['woods', 'caves']):
await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author} chose to hunt a {creature} with a {weapon} in {location}')
```

I think this is what you looking for, now, i don't know what library you use, but on disnake/pycord it works.

To do something when the user is selecting one of the choices you can do for example :

```
if weapon == 'sword': # this string needs to be the same with the one you introduced in the choices=[]
     . . . do stuff.
```

Comment: I've tried this and it returns this error:

AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Param'

Comment: @hydna1 well, as i said, i don't know what library do you use. if you use dpy 1.7.x there's no implementation for what you want.

Comment: if you wish to switch to Disnake, they it will work

Comment: Alright thanks, idk why I didn’t say it, but yes, I use discord.py 1.7